# И снова о кашах))

Tags: этимология

Пока писала о пшенице и пшене, подумала, что есть еще перловая каша, то есть, каша из перловки, хоть на самом деле, насколько я знаю, это ячмень. При чем же тут жемчуг (перл)?
А есть вообще ячка (если я ничего не путаю, это дробленая пшеница, но могу ошибаться). Тут не понятно совершенно, откуда название.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть крупа ячневая, есть перловая. Разница, насколько я понял, в том, что первая дроблёная, а вторая — цельная. Цельные зёрна напоминали жемчуг, потому якобы крупа и получила название "перловая".

Мне же кажется более вероятным происхождение от слова "пыро": http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0527.htm.

Что касается "ячки", то это, скорее, отсылка не к злаку, а к методу обработки, то есть расширение значения (тогда как у "пшена" произошло сужение).

Comment: От перла - крупа?   Это значит украшением заинтересовались раньше, чем едой.
То есть лозунг: хлеба и зрелищ, наоборот? Потехе время, а делу час?
Как - то не греет.  Пожрать все ж на первом месте, а то можно коньки откинуть, раньше, чем жемчуга найдешь. Я за пыро-перл --а потом похожее по форме на зерно -- горошина.
Насчет ячки, скорее наоборот, исходя из санскрита, ячмень был дробленым, а ячка цельным.  Корень мень возможно мелкоту и отображает. Всяко бывает. Попутали.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно очищенный ячмень напоминает жемчуг - перл, от этого и перловка, ячка производное от названия растения - ячмень, но вот слово ячмень по всем признакам имеет женский род с ударением на я, к сожалению, здравого толкования оного пока не выявляю.